# Join two files with AWK, one file from console

Tags: bash, awk

I can join two files using AWK like this:

```
awk 'NR=FNR{a[$2]=$2}{print $0, a[$1]}' FS="sep1" file1.txt FS="sep2" file2.txt
```

I can also use awk on file that is being processed:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2 file1.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | whatevercommands ... | awk '{print $0}'
```

Now how to join using awk the file that is being processed with exetrnal one and then use awk on them? Or rather how to feed awk one file that is being processed and the other new one. For eg.:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2 file1.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | manyMoreCommands ...| awk 'NR=FNR{a[$2]=$2}{print $0, a[$1]}}' FS="sep2" file2.txt
```

Examples are simplified. In the awk commands, I am doing loops and much more complicated things instead of simple prints.

What I really need is to be able to use the same mechanism that is used when joining two files (meaning AWK iterates over the first file then over the second one) but when one file is being fed from the command line.

Comment: I don't know awk, but I'd try passing `-` or `/dev/stdin` as the filename.

Comment: `echo bar | awk '{print NR,$0}' <(echo foo) -`

Comment: Please stop adding irrelevant tags to your question.